# Zend Mail Imap - copy email to sent folder

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, imap

I'm sending emails, but they don't appear in my sent folder. I understand why.

I have all IMAP information, how do I push a copy of the email into the sent folder?

Comment: you can use imap_append() for that

Comment: `Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap::appendMessage()`? (Non-Zend: `imap_append`)

Comment: @Wrikken The Zend function works.

Comment: You may want to upgrade your comment to an answer so the originator can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting @Wrikken's comment as an answer because it probably is the best answer for this ( based on the limited information provided originally ), and someone might not see it as a comment.

```
Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap::appendMessage()
```